# Equation or formula for calculating molecular orbital energies

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

Is there an equation, similar to the Rydberg formula, for calculating the energies of molecular orbitals?

For example, with the Rydberg formula, I can work out that the energy of a $1s$ orbital in hydrogen is $-13.6\ \mathrm{eV}$. Is there any way that I can calculate (or approximate) the energies of the bonding and anti-bonding orbitals in $\ce{H2}$?

Comment: It doesn't exist. Hydrogen atom can be solved exactly, multielectron systems can't.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I believe multi electron systems can be approximated by calculating Zeff (for example with Slater's rules) - are there any things like this for the MOs?

Comment: Well, for conjugated systems you can use the Hückel method for getting relative energies, but that's about it. Since this was tagged as computational chemistry: it's very easy to use computational chemistry to predict MO energies.

Comment: How would you go about doing it computationally? Are there any free software packages which are able to do it? Thank you.

Comment: I recommend [Psi4](http://psicode.org/). You can use [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/wiki/Main_Page) to help write input files and look at results.

Comment: For future googlers, the Avogadro link is broken, but https://avogadro.cc/ will get you there just fine.